# Post not showing up sometimes on website

Tags: posts, cache, hacks

I have a weird problem. A particular post is not showing up on my website sometimes. So If I clear cache then it shows up. It is happening only to one particular post. I am not able to figure out what the problem can be.

**Off-topic**:
That particular post is kind of controversial too. So I have a feeling that someone is trying to bring it down.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: What cache are you clearing? Browser? Proxy server? W3 (or similar plugin)?

Comment: I am using Total Cache for my website. I empty all cache everytime.

Comment: It's difficult to diagnose without knowing your full setup. When you say "someone is trying to bring it down", who could that be? Another WP user? Anyone else have access to your server/database?

Comment: Someone who I do not know, who do not access to any of my website related things

Comment: I very much doubt it's a malicious user - have you tried posting it again? (Admin -> Posts -> Add New, just copy/paste the content & delete the old one)